# YouTube hashtags don't appear on top of title if a location is set

Tags: youtube

Usually when adding hashtags to the video description, these tags will appear on top of the video title:

[image: youtubevideowithhashtagsontop]

Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCs9OEMfd2Q

However, when adding a location in the advanced settings, the tags are removed from the usual location space above the video title:

[image: youtubevideowithlocationontop]

Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhQ9vd4A_JI

I could not verify that this is documented behavior.
Is there any way to have both, location and hashtags above the title ?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Guess I have to add the hashtag to the title directly. Still, disappointing that this was noticed 3 years ago (or more) and youtube still hasn't addressed it?

Answer (score 4):

While I don't think this is documented, I believe this is the expected behavior. If a video is trending, it's hashtags also don't show up above the title.

Comment: I found this information documented in this page: https://www.tubics.com/blog/youtube-hashtags/